# Work with files, lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm nube in C++ programming and need your help.
Need to assign each sentence to variable sentence[i]
Not all letters are assigned. Why?

Code is wrong:

```
int k = 0;
char t[256];
string sentence[1024], s;
while(!in_file.eof())
{
    in_file.getline(str, num);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] != '.')
        {
            sentence[k] += str[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            sentence[k] += str[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    };

}
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << "Sentence" << i+1 << ": " << sentence[i] << endl;
```

Results:

```
My text from file:
У лукоморья дуб зеленый,
Золотая цепь на дубе том.
И днем, и ночью кот ученый
Все ходит по цепи кругом.

Sentence 1: Улкмрядбзлнй Злтяцп адб о.  // why?
Sentence 2: Иде,инчюктуеы Вехдтп еикуо. // why?
```

Comment: There are only two '.'s in your text. Maybe that's got something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
while( k < 1024 && in_file.getline( sentence[k],'.' ) )
{
    sentence[k] += '.';
    k++;

}
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << "Sentence" << i+1 << ": " << sentence[i] << endl;
```

It runs fine here http://ideone.com/lMnnW2 (using std::cin instead of in_file)